# react router dom v6 from json

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im learning react router dom, and im trying take the routes from one file with all routes.

But i give all times errors that is not route for example, or Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'.
I waste more than 4 hours with that without results, anyone can help me?

that is my app.jsx

```
    import react from 'react'
    import routes from './routes/routes.js'
    import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate, Router} from 'react-router-dom'
    import AppRoutes from './Components/AppRoutes'
    function App () {
      return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          {routes.map((rout) => ( 
            console.log(rout),
            <AppRoutes 
              key={rout.path}
              path={rout.path}
              component={rout.element}
              isPrivate={rout.isPrivate}
              />
          ))}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    
    )}
    
    export default App
```

routes.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import NotFound from '../Pages/NotFound';
    import Login from '../Pages/Login';
    import Dashboard from '../Pages/Dashboard';
    
    
    const routes = [
        {
            path: '/login',
            element: Login,
            isPrivate: false,
        },
        {
            path: '/dashboard',
            element: Dashboard,
            isPrivate: false,
        },
        {
            path: '/*',
            element: NotFound,
            isPrivate: false,
        },
    ];
    export default routes
```

and this is the component that returns the Routes

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";
     
    const AppRoutes = ({ component: Component,props, path, isPrivate, ...rest }) => {
        console.log("test")
     
        const userDetails = true
        return (
            <Route
                path={path}
                render={(props) => isPrivate && !Boolean(userDetails) ? (<Navigate replace to='/login'/>) : (<Component {...props} />)}
                {...rest}
            />)
    }
     
    export default AppRoutes
```

I upload it to github.
https://github.com/milfer322/login

Thanks so much!!!